# Don't find Sign In Page URL in Central Administration in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want created custom login page .

I created a .aspx page for login . but when i go to  Central Administration. Select Site from Application Management. Click on Authentication Provider.Select Zone , i don't find Sign In Page URL Section for  Change Custom Sign In Page URL.

**EDIT**

When i created web application , i selected "Classic Mode Authentication" . I should selected 
 "Claims Authentication" instead of Classic Mode Authentication, while create a web application.  :)

I use this code in power shell

```
$WebAppName = "http:// yourWebAppUrl"
$account = "yourDomain\yourUser"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName

Set-SPwebApplication $wa -AuthenticationProvider (New-SPAuthenticationProvider) -Zone  Default
```

Comment: Is your authentication type set to "Windows"?  If that is the case then you wont have the option for a custom login page.  You need to set your authentication type to "Forms".

Comment: No problem.  You should move your edit section into a new answer for this question and then accept your answer.  That way it will be marked as answered and people will know which response is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShel for this using the following cmdlet

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Login" -RelativePath "/_layouts/CustomLogin.aspx" -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"
```